# View Draft js output on react-native

Tags: react-native, draftjs

Consider Using Draft.js for rich text editing on the web app, then convert the output to a json object with Draft.js **convertToRaw** function and *store* it in the *database*.

if the consumer of the rich text is a react-native mobile application, what is the best approach to represent the rich text?

1. **is there any robust work or library that iterate through the json object and export native `Text` and `Image` components?**
2. also there are some libraries that export the json object to html:

   - https://github.com/sstur/draft-js-export-html
   - https://github.com/rkpasia/draft-js-exporter

the exported html then can be represented with a **webview** component. is this a reliable approach?

3. another way for representation would be putting **react** in react-native **webview** and use Draft.js `Editor` with **readOnly** prop. but I don't have any idea which way to go!

Answer (score 7):

1. **This seems to be the best approach.**
   You must fetch the json and write a parser that understands Draft.js model (`inlineStyleRanges`, `entityRanges`, `entityMap`,...) and based on that, exports to native components.
   At work we had the same problem, so we've developed a library that does the job, it's called [react-native-draftjs-render](https://github.com/globocom/react-native-draftjs-render).
   It has a sample project where you can see how it works and understand how to use it. It is also available on npm.
2. If you already have the html version and want to use it, you will also need a parser to convert the html into native components. [react-native-htmlview](https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview) seems to do it but I've never used.
3. Render native components is better than using webviews (they are very limited and slow), so I don't recommend this approach.

Answer (score 0):

We use [redraft](https://github.com/lokiuz/redraft) to approach that rich text from draft-js render to HTML5 and Weex([rax](https://github.com/alibaba/rax)). And I am sure you can use it achieve your goal because the redraft is just a convert function with zero dependencies, you can custom the render element like `div` in HTML or `View` in React Native.